# bootstrap progress bar not animating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've installed bootstrap to my `Rails 4` application using the [ruby gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

I have copied and pasted the code for an animated progress bar straight from [bootstraps docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-animated) into my page:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
   <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
      <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

But the bar is not animating. The only thing I can think of is the fact that I changed the bar's color in the `sass` variables.

Why isn't it animating?

**Edit**

What my bar looks like: 
[image: broken progress bar]

**Edit**

Here is the CSS being applied when I use the `active` class:
[image]

Comment: How did you change those colors?

Comment: @marzapower just changed the `$brand-primary` variable in my style sheet.

Comment: Was it ever working in your implementation (that is, before you made the color change)?

Comment: Are you using `Less stylesheets` or `css stylesheets`? I hope you followed all the instructions while installing the gem https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails I simulated the exact scenario as per the instructions and it worked like champ.

Comment: @KirtiThorat i think they are technically sass

Comment: @Deekor Not technically sass. Less is a JS based implementation and Sass is a Ruby based.

Comment: @KirtiThorat ok well its sass - which is what the gem i linked uses.

Comment: The animation for the progress bar is applied via css.  When you inspect your progress bar element in dev tools, do you see the .progress.active .progress-bar {
-webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
} styles being applied?

Comment: @jme11 yes, I've added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: If you want to use the sass files and change the variables should you use the [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). See [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/329-more-on-twitter-bootstrap) for more info.

Comment: @jokklan that is what i am using... did you even read the question?

Comment: You are linking to the [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), which is not the official bootstrap sass gem?

Comment: @jokklan my bad i linked the wrong repository, i am using the official gem however `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`

Comment: I tested it, and it worked fine, are you sure you didn't change anything else?

Answer (score 8):

It's just that the translucent white stripes (`rgba(255,255,255,.15)`) don't show up on certain colours.

Take the Chrome browser's `yellow`.  If we take that colour in Photoshop, then place a white stripe over it with .15 opacity, it's not visible.  I've put the outline on it here so you can see where the stripe is.

[image]

So for certain colours, you may need to adjust the alpha of the stripe colour.  I've added a class of `.progress-bar-primary` to the `.progress-bar`, in a similar way to how you'd add `.progress-bar-warning` etc.

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
    <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then for that `.progress-bar-primary`, just change the alpha of the stripe to your taste.  For the Chrome Yellow, I've used .75 opacity.

```
.progress-bar-primary {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.progress-striped .progress-bar-primary {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .75)   25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .75) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .75) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsbin.com/doyap/1/edit)**

Comment: I only changed tho color on one of the progress bars. If I try `progress-bar-info` for example its still not working. And I can see the white stripes.. they just are not moving.Ive added what my bar looks like to my question.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome. The animating bar looks fine on the bootstrap docs.

Comment: So when you reset the $brand-primary to what it was before it works again?

Comment: Oh I got confused when you said you changed the color of the sass variables, it sounded like before you did that, there was no problem.

Comment: Does the monitor even got a role/issue in this situation?

Comment: @diegoaguilar what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks @davidpauljunior! The demo provided was really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `class="bar"` with `class="progress-bar"`.

Answer (score 1):

Place the keyframes css at the top of your css file, not nested (if you uses sass) and don't add it in a media-query.

Comment: Check out this tutorial by the way, it's not using bootstrap but pretty cool: http://sarahjustine.com/2013/03/24/animated-progress-bars-with-css3-2/

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried reverting your changes to the colors? If not it may be worth trying that to see if it is your issue.

If thats nto the case i suggest you should default it back to stock and then just isolate it on its own and see how it goes. It may be a problem with other content in the html or something else confliting so if you load it into a blank document with stock settings.

I cant think of anything else at the moment. I hope it works.

Comment: Ya ive tried doing the stock stuff as well and its not working.

Comment: Did you re download bootstrap and try it?